# Dynamic Div id inside XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt

I am working on XSLT, which need to transform XML code into XHTML using XSL 1.0

I need Dynamic div id for making div collapse and expand.

Example:

```
<xsl:for-each select="queryresult/queryrows/row">
<!--Some Code -->
    <div id="headingOne" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
        <!--some code -->
    </div>
    <div aria-labelledby="headingOne" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
        <!--some code-->
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

I want to repeat this block for each row in my XML. But get unique DIV id such as headingOne, headingTwo etc..Any clues?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
<xsl:for-each select="queryresult/queryrows/row">
<!--Some Code -->
    <div id="{generate-id()}" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
        <!--some code -->
    </div>
    <div aria-labelledby="{generate-id()}" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
        <!--some code-->
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

to use a generated id value (format depends on the XSLT processor used, value can change each time the XSLT is executed) or you could use

```
<xsl:for-each select="queryresult/queryrows/row">
<!--Some Code -->
    <div id="heading{position()}" role="tab" class="panel-heading">
        <!--some code -->
    </div>
    <div aria-labelledby="heading{position()}" role="tabpanel" class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapseOne">
        <!--some code-->
    </div>
</xsl:for-each>
```

where you would get `heading1`, `heading2` and so one. If you really want to generate the English words for numbers like `One`, `Two`, you need more work.